# bash sh special parameter $@ "$@", save "$@" to a variable

Tags: bash, sh

when I am working on shell script, I am little frusturate on $@ and "$@" problem. So, I write a shell script to do some testing. like following.

```
func()
{
    local a="$@"
    for i in "$a";  do
        echo "$i ****"
    done
}

func000()
{
    local a="$@"
    for i in $a;  do
        echo "$i ****"
    done
}

func0()
{
    local a=$@
    for i in "$a";  do
            echo "$i ****"
    done
}

func00()
{
    local a=$@
    for i in $a;  do
        echo "$i ****"
    done
}

func1()
{
    for i in "$@";  do
        echo "$i ****"
    done
}

func2() 
{
    for i in $@;  do
        echo "$i ****"
    done
}

func "a b c"
func a b c 

echo "-----------"
func0 "a b c"
func0 a b c 

echo "-----------"
func00 "a b c"
func00 a b c 

echo "-----------"
func000 "a b c"
func000 a b c 

echo "-----------"
func1 "a b c"
func1 a b c 

echo "-----------"
func2 "a b c"
func2 a b c 




a b c ****
a b c ****   func
-----------
a b c ****   func0
a b c ****
-----------
a ****       func00
b ****
c ****
a ****
b ****
c ****
------------
a ****   func000
b ****
c ****
a ****
b ****
c ****

-----------
a b c ****     func1   //this has the result that I want. 
a **** 
b ****
c ****
----------- 
a ****      func2
b ****
c ****
a ****
b ****
c ****
```

As far as I remember, when using $@, we have to use double quoate, otherwise something will break. Therefore, I know some of functions definitely not work properly. (I still test it anyway)

**Only func1 gives me a desire result, however, the thing is I want to assign "$@" to a variable. by reviewing func0, func000, func0, func00 results, none of those give me correct stuff. So, I am hoping someone can help me out.**

In addition, I know sh and bash has difference. If someone can point me out in which condition something could break I will be so glad. Thanks.

---

update

I should say, this result of this script, it comes to the version of bash or sh, or freebsd sh vs linux sh.

I could be wrong, if so, just point it out, thanks a lot.

in old sh, freebsd sh, in which we do not have array, obviously, array assignment could not get working, the alternative is to use string like what I did in func000, local a="$a"; for i in $a; do ...

If using linux sh 4.5 (tested), or bash, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

update, thanks to @jordanm, I realize this is the difference between bash and old sh version somehow.

this is a solution in bash or sh 4.2.  in old sh, this might not be working.

```
  33 func3()                                                                         
  34 {                                                                               
  35     local a=("${@}")                                                            
  36                                                                                 
  37     for i in "${a[@]}"; do                                                      
  38         echo "$i ****"                                                          
  39     done                                                                        
  40 }
```

Comment: $@ is not a variable, it's an array of variables.

Comment: `$@` is not an array (`${@[1]}`, for example, is illegal). However, its behavior when quoted is special and array-like: `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...` (in contrast to `"$*"` which is essentially the same as `"$1 $2 $3 $4"`).

Comment: `local -a a=( "$@" )`, if you want to explicitly declare it as an array.

Comment: ...btw, this should work in bash much older than 4.2 (but won't work in any baseline `/bin/sh`, as arrays are an extension... as is the `local` keyword, though it's common enough that IIRC even ash has it).

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not him, the first I ever heard of saving `"${@}"` in this way was when I randomly happened by **[Rich's sh tricks](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html)**. There Rich offers many similarly helpful and most importantly *portably safe* methods to solve many common problems on his website, but here's an excerpt to address your current question:

**Working with arrays**

Unlike “enhanced” Bourne shells such as Bash, the POSIX shell does not have array types. However, with a bit of inefficiency, you can get array-like semantics in a pinch using pure POSIX sh. The trick is that you do have one (and only one) array — the positional parameters `“$1”`, `“$2”`, etc. — and you can swap things in and out of this array.

Replacing the contents of the `“$@”` array is easy:

```
set -- foo bar baz boo
```

Or, perhaps more usefully:

```
set -- *
```

What’s not clear is how to save the current contents of `“$@”` so you can get it back after replacing it, and how to programmatically generate these ‘arrays’. Try this function based on the previous trick with quoting:

```
save () {
 for i do printf %s\\n "$i" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/\$/' \\\\/" ; done
echo " "
}
```

Usage is something like:

```
myarray=$(save "$@")
set -- foo bar baz boo
eval "set -- $myarray"
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to keep everything in quotes you could try this:

```
test() {
    local args="$@"
    for i in `echo "$args"`;  do
        echo "$i ****"
    done
}

test 1 2 3 4
```

Output:

```
~ $ ./test.sh 
1 ****
2 ****
3 ****
4 ****
```

Comment: Your test isn't really valid, since all of his examples have args that contain spaces, which your example would also break on.

Comment: Fair point. I hadn't fully understood the question. My test does treat a single quoted argument with spaces the same as several arguments.